# Any way to remove all folders that contain only .DS_Store recursively?

Tags: terminal, finder

If I try

```
sudo find . -name '.DS_Store' -delete
```

then, within a few seconds, the `.DS_Store` files get re-created by Finder before

```
sudo find . -type d -empty -delete
```

can take effect.

I can do

```
sudo find . -name '.DS_Store' -delete; sudo find . -type d -empty -delete
```

but this only works on small trees. If there are many subfolders, Finder starts recreating before the 2nd command runs.

Comment: Could you please refine what you are trying to achieve? I can imagine you are doing some sort of development and want to avoid the .DS_Store files being in an archive/zip file...

Comment: There is a reason for those files, what's yours to want to remove them?

Comment: They are filling up a backup (made with CCC) and I don't need them in there.

Comment: If they show up on your CCC backup, shouldn't they also be on your original drive? Which filesystem type did you format your backup drive to (HFS, FAT etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Finder open to that folder? I don't see why the `.DS_Store` folders would be recreated unless you were viewing them.

If the folders are truly empty, you should be able to use `rm -rf <path>`. Be careful, it will completely remove that folder and any files in it. Do `man rm` to learn more.

*You shouldn't need the `sudo` unless you are touching system files. Don't do this unless you understand the ramifications.*